# Jquery click-event but not holding down/marking text-event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table wich expands/contracts on click. It works great, however, there is one problem, sometimes users might want to copy text in the table, and thus their line contracts(on the click)

Is there some way to avoid the event being triggerd on click but not if you hold the mouse down and/or mark text?

Sample page:
http://resihop.nu/search?from=&to=&when=&got_car=1&code=

I would much appriciate if you could supply an example, i'm not that used to javascript. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the event `mouseup` - rather than `click`. You could also check the length of time between `mousedown` and `mouseup` to decide if you should process the click.

---

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4PZvz/) should do the trick:

```
var lastMouseUp = 0, lastMouseDown = 0;
$('tr').bind('mouseup mousedown', function(e){
    var ms = new Date().getTime();
    e.type == 'mousedown' ? lastMouseDown = ms : lastMouseUp = ms;   

    if(e.type != 'mousedown' && (Math.abs(lastMouseUp - lastMouseDown)  < 300))
        console.log(Math.abs(lastMouseUp - lastMouseDown) + ' process click') // valid click
});
```

Comment: +1, Nice tactic :), although its not fall proof, what happens if a user double clicks to select all ?

Comment: @RobertPitt - I don't see how this would be a different problem from a `click` situation.

Comment: yea after reading more of his source i fully see the issue now.

Comment: this sounds like a great solution! Coul you or someone provide an example?

Comment: RobertPitt: I think this should work! On mouseup, hide, unless the mousedown was like three seconds before! The mouseup doesnt cut it though ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can also just refer the the first TR like so

```
$('.generals .odd').click(/*...*/).css("cursor","pointer");
```

sso that only the top row can be clicked, leaving the even `tr`'s event free.

another solution would be to do mouseup and check the text selection like so:

```
$('tr').mouseup(function(){
   selection = document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text;

   if(!selection)
   {
       //carry on to de-expand
   }
})
```